# Precedence of conjunctions: What is stronger: “ohne” or “und”?

Tags: conjunction, grammar-identification

I have two cases interpreting *A ohne B und C:*

1. *Und* is stronger than *ohne.* Thus I get:

   > (A ohne B) und (A ohne C)
2. *Ohne* is stronger than *und.* Thus I get:

   > (A ohne B) und (A with C)

I find more arguments speaking for case 1, than for case 2 as many languages tend to allow shortening sentences, if one can thereby avoid repeats keeping the essential informations.

Which kind of grammar applies here, where can I look it up?

Comment: Context is king. And no, _A_, _B_, _C_ don’t constitute context.

Comment: Somehow, this smells like set theory to me. If that's the case, `A - B ∪ C` would [probably be ambiguous](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/266182/order-of-precedence-of-set-operators). You'd need to add parentheses to clear it up. But in this case, it would be a mathematical viewpoint, not a linguistic or language related one. Human language typically is *very* reliant on context, connotations, unspoken understandings and so forth. It's much less formally strict than mathematics. In most cases, there *are* no rules to such a degree.

Comment: It can even depend on the cadence. "A - ohne B und C" and "A ohne B - und C" are different.

Comment: "Mir bitte einen Kaffe ohne Milch und Zucker" bedeutet ohne beides. "Mir bitte einen Kaffee ohne Milch und ein Stück Kuchen" bedeuet "ohne Milch, aber mit einem Stück Kuchen." Außer die Situationen wären kunstvoll entworfen um das gerade nicht zu sein.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the Q is about logics, not any linguistic matter

Comment: Your question made me wonder whether you know a language with a general rule for this!

Comment: @chirlu, seemingly in the end a context was not needed. I got my answer.  If you still want to have a context I could write a story and tell you have everything how I came to this question and why it is important to me. However I consider this some to be obstructive noise and by no means any relevant for the question. It doesn't help giving an answer, just might be more appealing/understandable for the majority.

Comment: @Beta, "with, and, without" are logical statements and should definetely belong to language.. + language should follow some rules/guidelines etc. to avoid msunderstandings, especially when matters are important.

Comment: @Ludi, I don't know one, however I don't find it hard to believe there to be such rules in many/most languages just not told/taught to people as they usually look for at the context, rathern than the exact wording of an expression.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Natural languages are not subject of mathematical logic. It can mean both. And this is not a special feature of German.

> Ich möchte Kaffee ohne Milch und Zucker.
>   I want coffee without milk and sugar.

This means:

> I want {coffee \ {milk ∪ sugar}}

But:

> Ich möchte Kaffee ohne Milch und Kekse.
>   I want coffee without milk and cookies.

This means:

> I want {{coffee \ milk} ∪ cookies}

It depends on the context.

Comment: Wobei ich den Satz mit den Keksen auch so verstehen könnte, dass jemand wirklich nur Kaffee möchte. (ist das "Kaffe" eigentlich mit Absicht? :-))

Comment: @ohno: Ich habe den *Kaffee* korrigiert. Weder ich noch die Rechtschreibprüfung haben das bemerkt. (Ilse wohnt in einem Kaff, Ernst in einem anderen, macht zusammen zwei **Kaffe**).

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Ich wäre in dem Fall für zwei *Käffer* (*Kuhkäffer*). Aber *Kaffe* könnte durchaus auch eine rechtschreibprüfungsgestattete Nebenform von *Kaffee* halte ;)

Comment: @Jan: Sowohl Wiktionary als auch Duden geben für *Kaff* gleich drei verschiedene Pluralformen an: Deine *Käffer*, meine irrtümlich eingeführten *Kaffe* und dann auch noch die *Kaffs* (die ich persönlich bevorzuge). Während der Duden die *Kaffe* als "selten" markiert, liste sie Wiktionary an erster Stelle auf. Die *Käffer* kommen bei Wiktionary erst als dritte Möglichkeit, und mein Rechtschreibprüfprogramm hält die *Käffer* schlichtweg für falsch (und möchte daraus einen Koffer machen), akzeptiert aber die *Kaffs* und *Kaffe*.